# Sea electricity problem

Tags: electricity

If salt water is a good conductor of electricity so does it mean if we put a very large voltage somewhere in the sea then person all across the world will experience some current and are there any physical parameters to quantify this.

Comment: The sea is well connected to, well, Earth ground. That said, you don't want to be in the water during a lightning storm.

Comment: It depends on the location of the person relative to the voltage source and the bottom of the sea and whether or not the voltage source is referenced to ground.